# Expanding menu shows text before expansion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made an expanding menu that will be my navigation menu. When you run it the text is showing when it isn't expanded. This is what I don't want, I want it hidden until the menu is expanded. I have tried to use `overflow: hidden;` but it doesn't work.
[JSFidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/somewhatme/wzfaozwe/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">Home</div><br />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1{
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 50px solid black;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#div1").hover(
        function() {
          $(this).animate({
            width: '+=800'
            }, 'slow'
          );
        },
        function() {
          $(this).animate({
            width: '-=800px'
            }, 'slow'
          );
        }
      );

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the text in a span so you can animate that separately. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rezg7hez/).

html:

```
<div id="div1"><span>Home</span></div><br />
```

css:

```
#div1{
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 50px solid black;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1 span").hide();

    $("#div1").hover(
        function() {
          $(this).animate({
            width: '+=800'
            }, 'slow'
          );

          $("span", this).show('slow');
        },
        function() {
          $(this).animate({
            width: '-=800px'
            }, 'slow'
          );

          $("span", this).hide('slow');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: @MorganClarke, please mark this question as answered.

Comment: @JusticeErolin Haha just beat me to it! Thanks

Comment: I need to wait at least 6 minutes until any question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqhfzcp5/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div1").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('show-text');
      $(this).animate({
        width: '+=800'
      }, 'slow');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('show-text');
      $(this).animate({
        width: '-=800px'
      }, 'slow');
    }
  );
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 50px solid black;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
#div1.show-text {
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Home</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem by using `color: transparent;` for the text and then each time the `div1` is hovered you toggle a class `expanded` for the `div1` element which has the `color: #fff;`. It looks nice and works good.

[Here is the jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wzfaozwe/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">Home</div><br />
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 50px solid black;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#div1.expanded {
  color: #fff;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#div1").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).animate({ width: '+=800' }, 'slow').toggleClass("expanded");
    },
    function () {
      $(this).animate({ width: '-=800px' }, 'slow').toggleClass("expanded");
    }
  );

});
```

Cheers.